# ion-input: check input on ionInput and set focus on next field

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am trying to build an ionic (angular) component to input a PIN. This would be 4 `ion-input` (one for each number) that accept only one character and that, on `ionInput` (when a key of the keyboard is pressed) checks the input and accepts (if it's `[0-9]`) or rejects it. If the input is accepted, then set focus on next field; if it's rejected, then delete it and keep focus on current field.
Well, I don't know why, but I don't succeed on it. The behavior of the `ion-input`s is not as expected.
With my code, what happens is that the input echoes to the next field and the focus is set on the after-next field. For example, I type a `1` on the field 0, then I get a `1` in field 0, another `1` in field 1 and the focus on field `2`; then I type a `9` in field 2 and a get a `9` in 2, another in 3 and the focus on `1`.

Anybody knows what's happening? And, the most important, how to solve it?
My code is the following:

```html
<ion-input *ngFor="let digit of digits; index as i"
               [id]="'digitField'+i"
               [(ngModel)]="digit"
               inputmode="decimal"
               (ionInput)="onFieldInput($event, i)"></ion-input>
```

```js
public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        this.digitFields = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < this.digits.length; i++) {
            this.digitFields[i] = document.getElementById('digitField' + i) as HTMLIonInputElement;
        }
    }

public onFieldInput($event, fieldIndex: number) {
        const newInput = $event.detail.data;
        const nextIndex = (fieldIndex + 1) % this.digits.length;
        const currentElement = this.digitFields[fieldIndex];
        let nextElement = this.digitFields[nextIndex];

        if (!/\d/.test(newInput)) {
            this.digits[fieldIndex] = '';
            currentElement.setFocus();
        } else {
            this.digits[fieldIndex] = newInput;
            nextElement.setFocus();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found a way to make it.

Before reading the code (which works now), I want to comment something: maybe there is a more simple way based on the code of the question, as I realized at some point that using the `digits` array in the html code was throwing problems, even when I only use it for the `*ngFor` init. Also, using `preventDefault()` and `stopImmediatePropagation()` helped at some point.

Anyway, when my code started working I already had given up with `ionInput` event long ago, that's why I use `keyDown` instead. Also `keyDown` gives me the chance to listen to backspace.

So, no more long introduction, here is the working snippet:

```html
<div class="pin-input-container" #fieldsContainer>
    <ion-input *ngFor="let n of dummyArray; index as i"
               type="text"
               inputmode="numeric"
               [type]="hideInput ? 'password' : 'text'"
               (keydown)="onKeyDown($event, i)"></ion-input>
</div>
```

```js
export class PinInputComponent {
    private static readonly TAG = 'PinInputComponent';

    @ViewChild('fieldsContainer') fieldsContainer;

    @Input() numberOfDigits = 4;
    @Input() hideInput = false;

    @Output() completed = new EventEmitter<string[]>();
    @Output() partial = new EventEmitter<string[]>();

    private digits: string[];
    public dummyArray: void[];

    public constructor() {
        this.dummyArray = new Array(this.numberOfDigits);
        this.digits = new Array(this.numberOfDigits);
    }

    public onKeyDown($event: KeyboardEvent, fieldIndex: number): void {
        $event.preventDefault();
        $event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        const domElement = $event.srcElement.parentElement as HTMLIonInputElement;

        if (/\d/.test($event.key)) {
            // Number: set field content, set digit in current position and go to next field
            domElement.value = $event.key;
            this.digits[fieldIndex] = $event.key;
            const nextField = domElement.nextElementSibling as HTMLIonInputElement;
            if (nextField) nextField.setFocus().then();

        } else if ($event.key === 'Backspace') {
            // Delete: clear content in field and this.digits and go to previous field
            domElement.value = null;
            this.digits[fieldIndex] = null;
            const previousField = domElement.previousElementSibling as HTMLIonInputElement;
            if (previousField) previousField.setFocus().then();

        } else {
            // Illegal key: clear field and stay there
            setTimeout(() => domElement.value = null, 10);
        }

        this.partial.emit(this.digits);

        // If the input was last digit and all digits are set, then emit completed
        if (fieldIndex >= this.digits.length - 1) {
            for (const digit of this.digits) {
                if (digit === null) {
                    return;
                }
            }

            this.completed.emit(this.digits);
        }
    }

    public setFocus(): void {
        (this.fieldsContainer.nativeElement.childNodes[1] as HTMLIonInputElement).setFocus().then();
    }
}
```

Note that I use a `setTimeout` if illegal character. I don't know the reason why, but it won't work without it. I guess that some process is woking in background in ionic and messes the focus and value propagation. I have tried even lower amounts of time and still works (left it to 10ms for security), but won't work without it.